# I need to schedule a Python script that open a database.txt in the same directory

Tags: python, selenium, scheduled-tasks

I tried using the method for a script only, but it didn't work. My script has to access the database.txt, to retrieve values that are essential for the flow of the program, but when I tried to schedule, it didn't run properly. These two files are in the same directory. I searched but almost every single question was about running a script that runs another one. I'm using Selenium with Python 3.9

The program scrapes Pixiv, and it gets the quantity of illustrations that a certain character specified in the program has. Then, it open the database.txt, search for the character in it, and updates the value. When the number of illustrations in the page is higher than the one I have on the database, it should update and do whatever I specified in the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import *
import requests, os
import datetime
import time
from sys import getsizeof

start = time.time()

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36 OPR/79.0.4143.73',
    'referer': 'https://www.pixiv.net/en/'
}

def open_browser(url):
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\codigos\\SeleniumDrivers\\geckodriver.exe', options=options)
    driver.set_window_position(3000,0)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(url)
    return driver

def login(driver, username, password):
    button_to_login = driver.find_element_by_class_name(
    'signup-form__submit--login'
    ).click()

    email_form = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
        'input[placeholder="E-mail address / pixiv ID"]'
    )
    email_form.send_keys(username)

    password_form = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
        'input[placeholder="password"]'
    )
    password_form.send_keys(password)

    login_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name(
        'signup-form__submit'
        ).click()

def take_aliase(japanese_name, english_name):
    with open('database.txt', 'a+', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.seek(0)
        character_names = [character_name.rstrip() for character_name in file]
        if not character_names:
            file.write(f'{english_name.lower()}/{japanese_name}/\n')
        else:
            formatted_names = []
            for character_name in character_names:
                character_name = character_name.split('/')[1]
                formatted_names.append(character_name)
                
            if japanese_name not in formatted_names:
                file.write(f'{english_name.lower()}/{japanese_name}/\n')
                    
def track_character(driver, character, another_character_name=""): # Pode ser colocado um *args para possíveis aliases e comparações de ilustrações
    """We are using the japanese name of the character for the search query of Pixiv."""
    """First the name in japanese, and in second the name in english."""

    # take_aliase('エミリア', 'Emilia')
    # take_aliase('中野三玖', 'Miku Nakano')
    take_aliase(character, another_character_name)
    #take_aliase('中野五月', 'Itsuki Nakano')

    recorded_num_illustration = 0
    english_name = ""
    japanese_name = ""

    with open('database.txt', 'a+', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.seek(0)
        character_names = [character_name.rstrip() for character_name in file]
        for character_name in character_names:
            english_name = character_name.split('/')[0]
            japanese_name = character_name.split('/')[1]
            if (character.lower() == english_name) or (character.lower() == japanese_name):
                character = japanese_name
                break

    search_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'sc-5ki62n-4'))
    )
    search_field.send_keys(character)
    search_field.submit()

    illustrations_page = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'a[href="/en/tags/{character}/illustrations?s_mode=s_tag"]')
        )
    ).click()

    driver.refresh()

    current_num_of_illustrations = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.CLASS_NAME, 'sc-1pt8s3a-8')
        )
    ).get_attribute('innerHTML')

    n = str(current_num_of_illustrations).split('.')
    current_num_of_illustrations = n[0] + n[1]
    current_num_of_illustrations = int(current_num_of_illustrations)

    recorded_num_illustration = get_recorded_num_of_illustrations(character)
    if recorded_num_illustration == "":
        recorded_num_illustration = current_num_of_illustrations
    else:
        recorded_num_illustration = int(recorded_num_illustration)
    
    if (current_num_of_illustrations) > (recorded_num_illustration):
        
        # list_of_images = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        #     EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
        #         (By.CLASS_NAME, 'l7cibp-2')
        #     )
        # )

        illustration_to_be_downloaded = ((current_num_of_illustrations) - (recorded_num_illustration))

        for i in range(4, illustration_to_be_downloaded + 4):
            image_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(                # <a> tags for the illustrations
                    (By.CLASS_NAME, 'rp5asc-16')
                )
            )[i].get_attribute('href')

            image_code = image_link.split('/')[-1]

            r = requests.get(f'https://www.pixiv.net/ajax/illust/{image_code}/pages?lang=en').json()
            image_links = [i['urls']['original'] for i in r['body']]
            for j in range(len(image_links)):
                im = requests.get(image_links[j], headers=headers)

                path = get_correct_path(english_name)
                current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
                # current_datetime = str(current_datetime).split('.')[0].split(' ')
                # current_datetime = current_datetime[0] + '-' + current_datetime[1]

                year   = current_datetime.strftime('%y')
                month  = current_datetime.strftime('%m')
                day    = current_datetime.strftime('%d')
                hour   = current_datetime.strftime('%H')
                minute = current_datetime.strftime('%M')
                second = current_datetime.strftime('%S')

                with open(os.path.join(path, english_name.title() + f" {year}-{month}-{day}--{hour}-{minute}-{second}.jpg",), 'wb') as file:
                    file.write(im.content)

    update_database(current_num_of_illustrations, character)
    
def get_recorded_num_of_illustrations(character_name):
    with open('database.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        lines = [line.rstrip() for line in file]
        
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        checker_japanese = lines[i].split('/')[1]
        checker_english = lines[i].split('/')[0]
        if (checker_japanese == character_name) or (checker_english == character_name.lower()):
            return lines[i].split('/')[2]

    print(f"There isn't {character_name} recorded.")
    
def update_database(current_num_of_illustrations, character_name):
    with open('database.txt', 'a+', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.seek(0)
        lines = [line.rstrip() for line in file]
        
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        new_line = []
        checker_japanese = lines[i].split('/')[1]
        checker_english = lines[i].split('/')[0]
        num_of_illustrations = lines[i].split('/')[2]
        new_line.append(checker_english)
        new_line.append(checker_japanese)
        new_line.append(num_of_illustrations)
        if (checker_japanese == character_name) or (checker_english == character_name.lower()):
            new_line[2] = current_num_of_illustrations
            new_line = f'{new_line[0]}/{new_line[1]}/{new_line[2]}'
        else:
            new_line = f'{new_line[0]}/{new_line[1]}/{new_line[2]}'
            
        lines[i] = new_line

    with open('database.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in lines:
            f.write(line + '\n')
  
def get_correct_path(character_name):
    if 'miku' in character_name:
        path = 'D:\Enrico\Imagens\Imagens_de_anime\Gotoubun\Miku'

    if 'emilia' in character_name:
        path = 'D:\Enrico\Imagens\Imagens_de_anime\Re Zero\Emilia\Teste-Scraping'

    return path


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://www.pixiv.net/en/'
    driver = open_browser(url)
    login(driver, 'pixivteste@gmail.com', 'teste1234#')
    track_character(driver, 'エミリア', another_character_name='Emilia')

    end = time.time()
    print(f'Runtime of the program: {end - start}.')`
```

But when I scheduled the task, it didn't update, even though it updates when I run it via VSCode. Is there a reason why?

Comment: _when I tried to schedule, it didn't run properly_ This doesn't tell us anything.  Did you get an error?  Please update the question to tell us _what the program actually did_, instead of just saying "it didn't work".

Comment: I'll update it, I'm sorry.

Comment: Show us the program code.  Otherwise we are just guessing what the problem is.

Comment: ok, I'll upload to github and post the link here.

Comment: You'll get better results posting the code directly in the question.  Many people won't bother to click an outside link.

Comment: all right, just edited it and put it there. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You're opening `database.txt` in the current directory, which is not necessarily the same directory where the program code is located.  As a debugging step, print the output of `os.getcwd()` to see where the file is being opened.

Comment: I put print(os.getcwd()) in all instances where I opened database.txt, but it returned me the same directory. I ran it through VSCode, is there a problem?

Comment: Did you look at the output of getcwd when running as a scheduled task?  I imagine the directory will be different than when you ran it in vscode.

Comment: "Scheduled" how? Do you mean run a `cron` job?

Comment: In the question you say "when I scheduled the task", so I mean however you did that.

Comment: oh, I used Windows Task Scheduler, and I didn't put any arguments and nothing on start in. I just put the script. Should I put some arguments?

Comment: Are you sure the scheduled task successfully runs?  Is there a log somewhere you can look at?

Comment: I opened up the historic of the task (in the properties of the task), and it says that the action and the task were concluded, but it didn't update the database nor download the illustration.

Comment: What is the exact command that is executed in the scheduler?

Comment: (By the way, from all these questions I'm having to ask, I hope you can see that your original question didn't have nearly enough details.)

Comment: yep, I see it. I didn't think it was this complex haha. I tried something different now,. I was running with the .py file, but I created a .bat file, and when the scheduler runs it, it gives this error:

log_file = open(log_path, "a+") if log_path is not None and log_path != "" else None
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'

Comment: I don't see any reference to `log_path` in your code.  Where is that error coming from?

Comment: from here:
File "C:\codigos\Python\Projeto_Pixiv\pixiv_illustration_checker.py", line 212, in <module>
    driver = open_browser(url)
  File "C:\codigos\Python\Projeto_Pixiv\pixiv_illustration_checker.py", line 21, in open_browser
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\codigos\\SeleniumDrivers\\geckodriver.exe', options=options)
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 160, in __init__
    self.service = Service(
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\service.py", line 44, in __init__